# LIbreoffice logs me out

Tags: libreoffice, logout

Each time that I start Libreoffice it logs me out of my current session. I am completely new to figuring these things out so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

xsession errors :
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the contents of the file `$HOME/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/433254/libreoffce-crashing-kubuntu-constantly (yet unanswered)

Comment: @terdon, if it's a Xserver crash as it seems, the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` has probably interesting info too.

Comment: @Rmano yes, but I'd check xsession-errors first since this seems to be a user-level thing.